# Javascript on Blade View Laravel Append Row

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

Hello i want ask you and hope find the answer of my problem here

This is My JS in blade view Laravel (i've change a little from CI)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var i = <?php echo $count ?>     //var i = '2'; only for try
            $('#datetime').datepicker({
                dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd"
            });

            $('#add').click(function(){
                i++;
                $('#tbanalisa tbody').append("<tr>"+"<td>"+i+"</td>"+"<td><textarea class=\"form-control\" rows=\"3\" name=\"analisa"+i+"\" placeholder=\"Analisa Penyebab\" style=\"resize: none; height: 50px\"></textarea></td>"+"<td><textarea class=\"form-control\" rows=\"3\" name=\"tindakan"+i+"\" placeholder=\"Tindakan Perbaikan dan Pencegahan\" Analisa Penyebab\" style=\"resize: none; height: 50px\"></textarea></td>"+"<td><input class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"pic"+i+"\" placeholder=\"PIC\"></td>"+"<td><input class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"tanggal_pelaksanaan"+i+"\" id=\"time"+i+"\" ></td>"+"</tr>");

            document.getElementById('count').value = i;
            });
});
```

---

Here is My Blade View (Laravel)

```
<tbody>
            @php
              $x = 1;
            @endphp
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $x ?></td>
                <td><textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="<?php echo "analisa".$x ?>" placeholder="Analisa Penyebab" style="resize: none;
                height: 50px"></textarea></td>
                <td><textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="<?php echo "tindakan".$x ?>" placeholder="Tindakan Perbaikan dan Pencegahan" 
                style="resize: none;
                height: 50px"></textarea></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="<?php echo "pic".$x ?>" placeholder="PIC"></td>
            @php
              $x++;
            @endphp
            </tbody>
```

Comment: This code is plain PHP + HTML + JavaScript and it should work as is in any PHP framework and template engine. I was wondering what exactly didn't work for you?

Comment: It must be work but idk why it doesn't.. its not error but its not adding row on mine. is there any wrong ?

Comment: @Christianus Andre did you load associated `js libraries` in laravel?.

Comment: I've update my question bro, i add my laravel blade view, but i delete datetime picker cause its too long

Comment: Undefined variable: count <-- I Got this error cause my JS include $count too

Comment: Post your code that contains that `count` variable

Comment: @NarendrasinghSisodia I've edit my code above please kindly look at that thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
var i = <?php echo $count ?>;
```

with

```
var i = {{ $count }};
```

If that doesn't work, post any Laravel/php/server errors you're receiving in your logs, etc.

Comment: Undefined variable: count

I've tried to replace $count with number '2' to try but it still cant adding row

Answer (score 0):

All the inputs which you are going to append should be in single line..

```
append("<tr>"+"<td>"+i+"</td>"+"<td><textarea class=\"form-control\" rows=\"3\" name=\"analisa"+......"</tr>");
```

Comment: Thanks for reply brother, it still cant adding row brother, please look around i've change my JS above, i try replace count with number '2' so it must be adding but in fact its not